# Sencha touch list tpl with nested data

Tags: extjs, nested, sencha-touch-2

I'm new to sencha. I'm create MVC structure by use sencha architect, touch 2.2.x version.

I want to show nested data to a list control but I'm not sure how to define the tmp.

Here is sample of data return from server

```
{
"data": 
[
    {"AcctId": 1, "AcctNum": "A", "Alias": "aa"},
    {"AcctId": 2, "AcctNum": "B", "Alias": "bb"}, 
    {"AcctId": 3, "AcctNum": "C", "Alias": "cc"}
]
}
```

this is model, I define nested model

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Data', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    uses: [
        'MyApp.model.LoginAlias'
    ],

    config: {
        hasMany: {
            model: 'MyApp.model.LoginAlias',
            name: 'LoginAlias'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.LoginAlias', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'AcctId'
            },
            {
                name: 'AcctNum'
            },
            {
                name: 'Alias'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

This is Stores to get data, It will be cross server data so I use JsonP

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyJsonPStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.Data'
    ],

    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'MyApp.model.Data',
        storeId: 'MyJsonPStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/test/get_alias/',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Finally the List

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyList', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',

    config: {
        store: 'MyJsonPStore',
        itemTpl: [
            '<div>List Item {AcctId}</div>'
        ]
    }

});
```

I can see that the Store can get data from server in Sencha Architect by click on the "eye" icon next to the Store.

I try the List tpl with data.AcctId or change List store to MyJsonPStore.data but all not work.

Please help, thanks very much.

p/s: I try with non-nested model, and the List work ok. And this is the main js file, In case it needed

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({

});

Ext.application({
    models: [
        'Data',
        'LoginAlias'
    ],
    stores: [
        'MyJsonPStore',
        'MyStore'
    ],
    name: 'MyApp',

    launch: function() {

        Ext.create('MyApp.view.MyList', {fullscreen: true});
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Data structure**

Not sure it's useful to define `MyApp.model.Data` as it's only the root of your list of data. So you could give away the `hasMany` logic.

**2. Data representation**

`Ext.dataview.List` is designed to show simple lists only. For nested lists, consider extending `Ext.dataview.NestedList`. (but if **1.** is true, you won't need it).

**3. Data access**

To get direct access to the data you need to display, simply add `rootProperty: 'data'` to your proxy's reader config object:

```
proxy: {
    type: "jsonp",
    url: 'http://server.ext/path/to/MyApp/app/data/sample.ashx',
    reader: {
        type: "json",
        rootProperty: 'data'
    }
}
```